# Prints out the number of multiples of 11 that are greater than or equal to N1 and less than or equal to N2

Tags: c

Write a program that does the following:

- Asks the user to enter an integer N1.
- Asks the user to enter an integer N2.
- Prints out the number of multiples of 11 that are greater than or equal to N1 and less than or equal to N2.

I already done it like this, but the program is asking to print out how many numbers that can multiply with 11 but has to be larger than N1 and smaller than N2, and that's where I'm having trouble with

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    int N1;
    printf("Enter an integer N1: ");
    scanf("%d", &N1);

    int N2;
    printf("Enter an integer N2: ");
    scanf("%d", &N2);

    int i = N1;
    while (i <= N2)
    {
        if (i % 11 == 0)
        {
            printf("%d\n", i);
        }
        i = i + 1;
    }
    printf("Exiting...");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is really no need for loops here. Think how you would tell it using pen and paper.

Comment: I’m too tired to write a proper answer, but basically: declare a variable `j` at the top, initialise it to zero, increment it every time `i % 11 == 0` (in your existing `if` block), and print it at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an additional counter variable to keep track of this. Some additional improvements:

1. When using `scanf` it is best to always prepend your input format with a space so any leading whitespace in the buffer is consumed but not formatted into the output variables, and also to check its return value for success (it returns an `int` representing the number of format specifiers successfully read from the string).
2. You don't need to iterate one at a time. You can increment `N1` to the next multiple of 11, then keep adding 11 to that until it hits the value of `N2`.

   ```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main() 
    {
        int N1;
        printf("Enter an integer N1: ");
        if (scanf(" %d", &N1) != 1)
        {
            // Handle scanf failure
        }

        int N2;
        printf("Enter an integer N2: ");
        if (scanf(" %d", &N2) != 1)
        {
            // Handle scanf failure
        }

        while (N1 % 11 != 0)
        {
            N1++;
        }

        int count = 0;

        while (N1 < N2)
        {
            printf("%d\n", N1);

            N1 += 11;
            count++;
        }

        printf("Saw %d multiples of 11 in this range.\n", count);

        printf("Exiting...");
        return 0;
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

For this answer, I started by copying your code, adding the `scanf` improvements from Govind Parmar’s answer, and adding a counter variable.

Now I want to build on Eugene Sh.’s comment by getting rid of the loop completely. This means my answer won’t print out each multiple of 11, but you didn’t need to do that anyway.

To start with, we need to check that `N2 >= N1` is true. When we use a loop, the loop doesn’t execute if this condition is false, but when we get rid of the loop, we need to check this condition manually.

For the main part of the problem, think of it this way: You have a range of numbers, starting at `N1` and ending at `N2`. You want to determine how many multiples of 11 are in that range. To do this, find the smallest multiple of 11 in that range, find the largest multiple of 11 in that range, and find out how many multiples of 11 are between them.

To find the smallest multiple of 11 that is greater than or equal to `N1`, first find the largest multiple that is less than or equal to 11 (`N1 / 11`), then add 11 if necessary.

To find the largest multiple of 11 that is less than or equal to `N2`, just do `N2 / 11`.

Call these multiples `smallest_multiple` and `largest_multiple`, respectively. Now, to find how many multiples there are in total, do `(largest_multiple - smallest_multiple) / 11 + 1`.

Putting it all together:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    int N1;
    printf("Enter an integer N1: ");
    if (scanf(" %d", &N1) != 1) {
        // Handle scanf failure
    }

    int N2;
    printf("Enter an integer N2: ");
    if (scanf(" %d", &N2) != 1) {
        // Handle scanf failure
    }

    int count;

    if (N2 >= N1) {
        int smallest_multiple;
        int largest_multiple;

        smallest_multiple = N1 / 11;
        if (smallest_multiple < N1) {
            smallest_multiple += 11;
        }

        largest_multiple = N2 / 11;

        if (largest_multiple >= smallest_multiple) {
            count = (largest_multiple - smallest_multiple) / 11 + 1;
        } else {
            count = 0;
        }
    } else {
        count = 0;
    }

    printf("Saw %d multiples of 11 in this range.\n", count);

    printf("Exiting...");
    return 0;
}
```

There is one possible problem with this answer: it might not work properly if `N1 < 0`. Unfortunately most guides to C arithmetic operators seem to ignore negatives when it comes to division. The best I found so far is https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic:

> The quotient is rounded in implementation-defined direction. (until C++11)
>
> The quotient is truncated towards zero (fractional part is discarded). (since C++11)

I’ll update this answer when I know more.

---

**Edit:** I found a problem with my original answer. If there are no multiples of 11 in the range, than `smallest_multiple` will be greater than `N2` (outside the range), `largest_multiple` will be less than `N1` (outside the range) and `largest_multiple - smallest_multiple == -11`. I have edited my answer to test for this.